# Selecting specific array content after splitting [Python2.7]

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am currently having trouble with selecting contents of my array. The array contents can be altered so I have created `import` method and used `threading` to update the data.

I will be using Tkinter as my GUI and I want my button to return the content of the array once clicked.

My array is like : `myarray = ["Uno:Dos:Tres:Quatro","One:Two:Three:Four","A:B:C:D"]`.

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

myarray = []
class Dummy:
    def Sth(self):
        global myarray
        myarray = ["Uno:Dos:Tres:Quatro","One:Two:Three:Four","A:B:C:D"]
        master = Tk()
        master.grid()
        for x in myarray:
            x = x.split(":")
            self.frame = Frame(master)
            self.frame.pack()
            self.thebutton = Button(self.frame,text=x[0],command=lambda: self.doFoo(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]))
            self.thebutton.pack()

        master.mainloop()
    def doFoo(self,first,second,third,fourth):
        popup = Tk()
        popup.grid()
        Label(popup,text=first).pack()
        Label(popup,text=second).pack()
        Label(popup,text=third).pack()
        Label(popup,text=fourth).pack()
        popup.mainloop()
A = Dummy()
A.Sth()
```

Problem: After clicking the button, the contents of the popups are `A,B,C,D`.

What I expected was:

- Click Uno -> `Uno,Dos,Tres,Quatro`
- Click One -> `One,Two,Three,Four`

### Any help please? Thanks!

I tried doing:

```
        for index,x in enumerate(myarray):
            x = x.split(":")
            self.frame = Frame(master)
            self.frame.pack()
            self.thebutton = Button(self.frame,text=x[0],command=lambda index=index: self.doFoo(x[index][0],x[index][1],x[index][2],x[index][3]))
```

But I get `IndexError: string index out of range`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about your `for` loop: it's creating three buttons that all have the same variable `x`, and the callback to `doFoo()` is *always* going to get passed the last item in your list.

If you assign x=x in your lambda expression, each command will retain information from its iteration of the loop. You need to reformat your loop like this:

```
for x in myarray:
    x = x.split(':')
    Button(self.frame, text=x[0], command = lambda x=x: self.doFoo(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3])).pack()
```

and put this:

```
self.frame = Frame(master)
self.frame.pack()
```

outside your for loop.

For more info, see: http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm